# $$hashKey not generating new value while push() new object in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I found a problem with generating new $$hashKey.
In this code:

```
this.list = '[{
    "body": "asdf",
    "tag": "resolved",
    "time": "2147483647",
    "id": "51"
}, {
    "body": "asdf",
    "tag": "undone",
    "time": "2147483647",
    "id": "138"
}, {
    "body": "asdf",
    "tag": "undone",
    "time": "2147483647",
    "id": "139"
}]';

this.addTask = function(body) {

    newObj.body = body;
    newObj.tag = 'undone';
    newObj.time = Date.now();

    this.list.push(newObj);
}
```

When I add second object its $$hashKey the same. And I have an error while `ng-repeat` `this.list`.

How to increment it manually or there is simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
this.addTask = function(body) {
    var newObj = { body : body, tag :'undone', time: Date.now() };    
    this.list.push(newObj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Fast answer, really works! My problem was that, I created object outside of function

Comment: or add `var newObj  = {}` before the rest